# console log and adding values from multiple switch statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement

I am trying to add multiple values from my switch statement (`value`, `breakMonValue`, `finishMonValue`) so I can `console.log` these values added together, and would like to know if this is possible?

[image]

Not defined startMonTimeStr variable

```
function _slicedToArray(arr, i) { return _arrayWithHoles(arr) || _iterableToArrayLimit(arr, i) || _nonIterableRest(); }

function _nonIterableRest() { throw new TypeError("Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance"); }

function _iterableToArrayLimit(arr, i) { var _arr = []; var _n = true; var _d = false; var _e = undefined; try { for (var _i = arr[Symbol.iterator](), _s; !(_n = (_s = _i.next()).done); _n = true) { _arr.push(_s.value); if (i && _arr.length === i) break; } } catch (err) { _d = true; _e = err; } finally { try { if (!_n && _i["return"] != null) _i["return"](); } finally { if (_d) throw _e; } } return _arr; }

function _arrayWithHoles(arr) { if (Array.isArray(arr)) return arr; }

var timeStringToValue = function timeStringToValue(timeStr) {
  var _timeStr$match = timeStr.match(/(\d+):(\d+) ([ap]m)/),
      _timeStr$match2 = _slicedToArray(_timeStr$match, 4),
      hours = _timeStr$match2[1],
      minutes = _timeStr$match2[2],
      ampm = _timeStr$match2[3];

  var ampmHourModifier = ampm === 'pm' ? 12 : 0;
  return Number(hours) + ampmHourModifier + minutes / 60;


};

var startMonTimeStr = $('.start-time-monday option:selected').text();
var startMonValue = timeStringToValue(startMonTimeStr);


console.log(timeStringToValue(StartMonValue));
console.log(timeStringToValue('3:30 pm'));
```

They are laid out like this:

```
$('.start-time-monday').each(function(){
    $(this).change(function(){

        var monTime = 


        $('.start-time-monday').each(function(){
        $(this).change(function(){

                var monTime = $('.start-time-monday option:selected').text();
                var value = "";

            switch(monTime){
              case "7:00 am":
                value = 7.00;
                        break;
              case "7:15 am":
                value = 7.25;
                        break;
              case "7:30 am":
                value = 7.50;
                        break;
              case "7:45 am":
                value = 7.75;
                        break;
              case "8:00 am":
                value = 8.00;
                        break;
              case "8:15 am":
                value = 8.25;
                        break;
              case "8:30 am":
                value = 8.50;
                        break;
              case "8:45 am":
                value = 8.75;
                        break;
              case "9:00 am":
                value = 9.00;
                        break;
              case "9:15 am":
                value = 9.25;
                        break;
              case "9:30 am":
                value = 9.50;
                        break;
              case "9:45 am":
                value = 9.75;
                        break;
              case "10:00 am":
                value = 10.00;
                        break;
              case "10:15 am":
                value = 10.25;
                        break;
              case "10:30 am":
                value = 10.50;
                        break;
              case "10:45 am":
                value = 10.75;
                        break;
              case "11:00 am":
                value = 11.00;
                        break;
              case "11:15 am":
                value = 11.25;
                        break;
              case "11:30 am":
                value = 11.50;
                        break;
              case "11:45 am":
                value = 11.75;
                        break;
              case "12:00 pm":
                value = 12.00;
                        break;
              case "12:15 pm":
                value = 12.25;
                        break;
              case "12:30 pm":
                value = 12.50;
                        break;
              case "12:45 pm":
                value = 12.75;
                        break;
              case "1:00 pm":
                value = 13.00;
                        break;
              case "1:15 pm":
                value = 13.25;
                        break;
              case "1:30 pm":
                value = 13.50;
                        break;
              case "1:45 pm":
                vaue = 13.75;
                        break;
              case "2:00 pm":
                value = 14.00;
                        break;
              case "2:15 pm":
                value = 14.25;
                        break;
              case "2:30 pm":
                value = 14.50;
                        break;
              case "2:45 pm":
                value = 14.75;
                        break;
              case "3:00 pm":
                value = 15.00;
                        break;
              case "3:15 pm":
                value = 15.25;
                        break;
              case "3:30 pm":
                value = 15.50;
                        break;
              case "3:45 pm":
                value = 15.75;
                        break;
              case "4:00 pm":
                value = 16.00;
                        break;
              case "4:15 pm":
                value = 16.25;
                        break;
              case "4:30 pm":
                value = 16.50;
                        break;
              case "4:45 pm":
                value = 16.75;
                        break;
              case "5:00 pm":
                value = 17.00;
                        break;
              case "5:15 pm":
                value = 17.25;
                        break;
              case "5:30 pm":
                value = 17.50;
                        break;
              case "5:45 pm":
                value = 17.75;
                        break;
              case "6:00 pm":
                value = 18.00;
                        break;
              case "6:15 pm":
                value = 18.25;
                        break;
              case "6:30 pm":
                value = 18.50;
                        break;
              case "6:45 pm":
                value = 18.75;
                        break;
              case "7:00 pm":
                value = 19.00;
                        break;
              case "7:15 pm":
                value = 19.25;
                        break;
              case "7:30 pm":
                value = 19.50;
                        break;
              case "7:45 pm":
                value = 19.75;
                        break;
                    default:
                      value = '0';
                        break;
              }

          //var startTimeMon = timeSwitch(monTime) ;
          console.log(value, 'Monday Start time value');
        });

  });


    $('.meal-break-monday').each(function(){
    $(this).change(function(){

            var breakMonTime = $('.meal-break-monday option:selected').text();
            var breakMonvalue = "";

        switch(breakMonTime){
          case "15 mins":
            breakMonvalue = 0.25;
                    break;
          case "30 mins":
            breakMonvalue = 0.50;
                    break;
          case "45 mins":
            breakMonvalue = 0.75;
                    break;
          case "60 mins":
            breakMonvalue = 1.00;
                    break;
                default:
                  value = '0';
                    break;
          }

      //var startTimeMon = timeSwitch(monTime) ;
      console.log(breakMonvalue, 'Mon BREAK time value');
    });


});





//finish time monday
  $('.finish-time-monday').each(function(){
    $(this).change(function(){

            var finishMonTime = $('.finish-time-monday option:selected').text();
            var finishMonvalue = "";

        switch(finishMonTime){
          case "7:00 am":
            finishMonvalue = 7.00;
                    break;
          case "7:15 am":
            finishMonvalue = 7.25;
                    break;
          case "7:30 am":
            finishMonvalue = 7.50;
                    break;
          case "7:45 am":
            finishMonvalue = 7.75;
                    break;
          case "8:00 am":
            finishMonvalue = 8.00;
                    break;
          case "8:15 am":
            finishMonvalue = 8.25;
                    break;
          case "8:30 am":
            finishMonvalue = 8.50;
                    break;
          case "8:45 am":
            finishMonvalue = 8.75;
                    break;
          case "9:00 am":
            finishMonvalue = 9.00;
                    break;
          case "9:15 am":
            finishMonvalue = 9.25;
                    break;
          case "9:30 am":
            finishMonvalue = 9.50;
                    break;
          case "9:45 am":
            finishMonvalue = 9.75;
                    break;
          case "10:00 am":
            finishMonvalue = 10.00;
                    break;
          case "10:15 am":
            finishMonvalue = 10.25;
                    break;
          case "10:30 am":
            finishMonvalue = 10.50;
                    break;
          case "10:45 am":
            finishMonvalue = 10.75;
                    break;
          case "11:00 am":
            finishMonvalue = 11.00;
                    break;
          case "11:15 am":
            finishMonvalue = 11.25;
                    break;
          case "11:30 am":
            finishMonvalue = 11.50;
                    break;
          case "11:45 am":
            finishMonvalue = 11.75;
                    break;
          case "12:00 pm":
            finishMonvalue = 12.00;
                    break;
          case "12:15 pm":
            finishMonvalue = 12.25;
                    break;
          case "12:30 pm":
            finishMonvalue = 12.50;
                    break;
          case "12:45 pm":
            finishMonvalue = 12.75;
                    break;
          case "1:00 pm":
            finishMonvalue = 13.00;
                    break;
          case "1:15 pm":
            finishMonvalue = 13.25;
                    break;
          case "1:30 pm":
            finishMonvalue = 13.50;
                    break;
          case "1:45 pm":
            finishMonvaue = 13.75;
                    break;
          case "2:00 pm":
            finishMonvalue = 14.00;
                    break;
          case "2:15 pm":
            finishMonvalue = 14.25;
                    break;
          case "2:30 pm":
            finishMonvalue = 14.50;
                    break;
          case "2:45 pm":
            finishMonvalue = 14.75;
                    break;
          case "3:00 pm":
            finishMonvalue = 15.00;
                    break;
          case "3:15 pm":
            finishMonvalue = 15.25;
                    break;
          case "3:30 pm":
            finishMonvalue = 15.50;
                    break;
          case "3:45 pm":
            finishMonvalue = 15.75;
                    break;
          case "4:00 pm":
            finishMonvalue = 16.00;
                    break;
          case "4:15 pm":
            finishMonvalue = 16.25;
                    break;
          case "4:30 pm":
            finishMonvalue = 16.50;
                    break;
          case "4:45 pm":
            finishMonvalue = 16.75;
                    break;
          case "5:00 pm":
            finishMonvalue = 17.00;
                    break;
          case "5:15 pm":
            finishMonvalue = 17.25;
                    break;
          case "5:30 pm":
            finishMonvalue = 17.50;
                    break;
          case "5:45 pm":
            finishMonvalue = 17.75;
                    break;
          case "6:00 pm":
            finishMonvalue = 18.00;
                    break;
          case "6:15 pm":
            finishMonvalue = 18.25;
                    break;
          case "6:30 pm":
            finishMonvalue = 18.50;
                    break;
          case "6:45 pm":
            finishMonvalue = 18.75;
                    break;
          case "7:00 pm":
            finishMonvalue = 19.00;
                    break;
          case "7:15 pm":
            finishMonvalue = 19.25;
                    break;
          case "7:30 pm":
            finishMonvalue = 19.50;
                    break;
          case "7:45 pm":
            value = 19.75;
                    break;
                default:
                  value = '0';
                    break;
          }

      //var startTimeMon = timeSwitch(monTime) ;
      console.log(finishMonvalue, 'Mon FINISH time value');
    });


});
```

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be more elegant to parse the time string into a number with math, eg:

```js
const timeStringToValue = (timeStr) => {
  const [, hours, minutes, ampm] = timeStr.match(/(\d+):(\d+) ([ap]m)/);
  const ampmHourModifier = ampm === 'pm' ? 12 : 0;
  return Number(hours) + ampmHourModifier + (minutes / 60)
};

console.log(timeStringToValue('10:00 am'));
console.log(timeStringToValue('3:30 pm'));
```

And then you can call it:

```
const startMonTimeStr = $('.start-time-monday option:selected').text();
const startMonValue = timeStringToValue(startMonTimeStr);
```

and

```
const finishMonTimeStr = $('.finish-time-monday option:selected').text();
const finishMonValue = timeStringToValue(finishMonTimeStr);
```

`switch` is unnecessarily verbose and ugly in most cases, and this is no exception.

If you want to add all the totals up, have a change calculate each subtotal, eg:

```
const getBreakTotal = () => {
  const minutes = $('.meal-break-monday option:selected').text().match(/^\d+/)[0];
  return minutes / 60;
};
const getAllTotals = () => {
  const startTotal = timeStringToValue($('.start-time-monday option:selected').text());
  const breakTotal = getBreakTotal();
  const finishTotal = timeStringToValue($('.finish-time-monday option:selected').text());
  console.log(startTotal + breakTotal + finishTotal);
};

$('.start-time-monday, .meal-break-monday, .finish-time-monday').on('change', getAllTotals);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, I am actually trying to give values to the time as in the end I would want to be able to calculate this hence why I am doing a switch case with giving them values. Would you know how to do this with those values?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what additional functionality you're looking for - in the answer, the `timeStr` is dynamic, anything can call `timeStringToValue` with whatever time string needs to be parsed, and the appropriate value will be returned.

Comment: A drop down menu will have times which will then reference a value, these values are going to be calculated to get the total number of hours. If that helps

Comment: Just add up all of the values retrieved from `timeStringToValue`..?

Comment: Thanks, sorry, I just wasn't understanding your answer before hence multiple posts, but dumb question to call the function is it

console.log(timeStringToValue(const finishMonTimeStr = $('.finish-time-monday option:selected').text();
 ));

I'm just not a technical person haha

Comment: Declaring a variable is a statement, which cannot exist where an expression is expected, like inside a `console.log`. If you want to declare the variable, do it on the above line, then `console.log` the variable on the next line

Comment: I've tried declaring it in the line above for a test time 

so my code looks like this
testTime = '12 am'
console.log(timeStringToValue(testTime));

however I am getting an uncaught type error?

Comment: I've also had to convert this to ES5 because the browser doesn't support es6 syntax :)

Comment: Edit, all good, i've found out I didn't name the variable correctly :)

Comment: Your original question does not have anything like `12 am` - they all contain minutes as well. Use `12:00 am` instead, like your original question. Best to do web development on a modern browser, and then automatically transpile code to ES5 for obsolete browsers later using Babel

Comment: thanks, yeah, I figured that one out. Also its saying that StartMonTimeStr is not defined when it is? I have copied the code above where my question was.

Comment: The code in the answer uses a lowercase `s`, so `StartMonTimeStr` won't work - use `startMonTimeStr` instead

Comment: Thanks, last question, when I try and change values from the dropdown, it will only show the first default value as it is 7:00am but when I try and change the dropdown it won't change? 

eg when I load the page the time will say 7:00am with it console logged with a value of 7, but when I change it to 7:15 the value does not change?

Comment: Does the function run? Without actually seeing the dropdowns, it's hard to say where exactly the issue is - need a [MCVE]

Comment: I have just uploaded a screenshot for you to see what I am seeing, I have also console logged the monday finish time hence why you are seeing two 7 values.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] - a screenshot of what is logged doesn't allow others to reproduce the problem you're having

Comment: Yes, the function is running as values are showing, its just not changing values when I change times. If that helps.

Comment: It's not possible to understand what the issue is without a [MCVE] to debug - please edit one into your question, ideally, a runnable Stack Snippet, so others can reproduce the error as well

Comment: with this function 

const timeStringToValue = (timeStr) => {
  const [, hours, minutes, ampm] = timeStr.match(/(\d+):(\d+) ([ap]m)/);
  const ampmHourModifier = ampm === 'pm' ? 12 : 0;
  return Number(hours) + ampmHourModifier + (minutes / 60)
};

console.log(timeStringToValue('10:00 am'));
console.log(timeStringToValue('3:30 pm'));

How would I change the 'pm' into 'mins' when selecting values for the meal break?

here is an example fiddle of what I mean

https://jsfiddle.net/tjhunt03/npLxq0hm/

Comment: This is beginning to sound like a [chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) - converting `mins` is completely different. If the code in the answer doesn't work for you, please post a [MCVE] demonstrating the problem - otherwise, if it works (as the "Run code snippet" button demonstrates, to the best of the knowledge of readers), consider accepting it